# Springboot Service, ServiceImpl and Repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Many Spring Boot applications are structured with a Repository, Service and Service Implementation.

Example:

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Long> {

    Optional<Car> findById(Long id);    
}
```

**CarService**

```
public interface CarService {
Optional<Car> findById(Long id);
}
```

**CarServiceImpl**

```
@Service
@Transactional
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CarServiceImpl implements CarService {
    private final CarRepository carRepository;

    @Override
    public Optional<Car> findById(Long id) {
        return carRepository.findById(id);
    }    
}
```

Now on the controller for example I have seen:

**Car Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CarController {

@Autowired
private final CarService carService

    // GET ONE CAR
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Optional<Car>> find(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header("Custom-Header", "foo")
                .body(carService.findById(id));
    }
```

But if I need to save a car I need access to:

```
@Autowired
private final CarRepository carRepository
```

And then a method on the controller like:

```
// SAVE ONE CAR
@PostMapping("/")
Car newCar(@RequestBody Car car) {
    return carRepository.save(car);
}
```

Q: Can it be explained why when saving entities I access the repository directly and when querying I go through the service implementation?

Are some CRUD methods getting default implementations?

Comment: I don't understand your question, what issue or error are you facing at the moment ?

Comment: Querying goes through the service, save/delete goes through the repo directly. Why.

Comment: You can use your service for all requests, just add a "save"  method and any other relevant methods to your service .

Comment: it's just how the code is written, you could have everything in a service, or call everything from the repo directly. It's just a matter of code design then

Comment: Should I access the service or the service implementation?

Comment: Add mehod to the service, you should be programming to interfaces not the implementation (if there is just 1 implementation just ditch the interface). The `@Repository` on the interface is useless to, it doesn't add anything to a Spring Data repository as it is detected otherwise.

Comment: i recommend you to check this [Q/A](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/411026/layered-architecture-horizontal-dependencies)

Comment: Does below answer look setup correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Repository**

```
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Long> {
    // remove this method because it's provided by CrudRepository
    Optional<Car> findById(Long id);
}
```

**SERVICE**

```
public interface CarService {
    Optional<Car> findById(Long id);
    Car saveCar(Car car);
}
```

**SERVICE IMPLEMENTATION**

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CarServiceImpl implements CarService {
private final CarRepository carRepository;

@Override
public Car findById(Long id) {

    return carRepository.findById(id).orElse("return something if car by id is not present in database");
}

@Override
public Car saveCar(Car car) {
    return carRepository.save(car);
    }
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CarController {

private final CarService carService;

// GET ONE CAR
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Car> find(@PathVariable Long id) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header("Custom-Header", "foo")
            .body(carService.findById(id);
}

// SAVE ONE CAR
@PostMapping("/")
ResponseEntity<Car> newCar(@RequestBody Car Car) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(carService.saveCar(car));
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok - so the Controller uses the service not the implementation of it and you have the .orElse - I presume there is a way to pass a message to the front end?
What about error handling on the save?

Comment: just let me know if i it holp you

Comment: Yes, use interface not implementation spring framework will inject it for you, orElse is for the case when the object with this id is not found, in another way(Optional- used to represent a value that may or may not be present), for  exception handling, please check official documentation

Answer (score 0):

I discovered you can refer to `entityRepository.save` without a save method on the Repository as it is part of the CRUD methods you get by default.

Add your own save methods to the service and repository. Setup like this:

**REPOSITORY**

```
@Repository // DELETE @Repository?
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Long> {

    Optional<Car> findById(Long id);
    // No need for save method here as provided by CRUD out of the box
}
```

**SERVICE**

```
public interface CarService {

    Optional<Car> findById(Long id);
    public Car saveCar(Car car);
}
```

**SERVICE IMPLEMENTATION**

Any business logic associated goes in this service implementation.

```
@Service
@Transactional
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CarServiceImpl implements CarService {
private final CarRepository carRepository;

@Override
public Optional<Car> findById(Long id) {
    return carRepository.findById(id);
}


public Car saveCar(Car car) {
    return carRepository.save(car);
    }
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CarController {

@Autowired
private final CarServiceImpl carServiceImpl;

// GET ONE CAR
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Optional<Car>> find(@PathVariable Long id) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header("Custom-Header", "foo")
            .body(carServiceImpl.findById(id));
}

// SAVE ONE CAR
@PostMapping("/")
Car newCar(@RequestBody Car Car) {
    return carServiceImpl.saveCar(car);
   }
}
```

Comment: i added a answer with edited version of this one